# how to fix error after running reactjs first code

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and trying to run code but showing error. I m not getting proper solution about this error.

I newly install reactjs , node js and running first time on xampp localhost. I tried

1. **npm install @babel/core** --> this installed @babel/core 7.4.4
2. **npm install babel-core --save-dev** --> this set babel/core to 6.26

{
"name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    **"@babel/core": "^7.4.4",**
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    **"babel-core": "^6.26.3",**
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0"
  }
}

I already run npm command from command prompt to update babel/core and expecting upgradation but every time same version and showing error.
[highlighted area in image with blue color is main error to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxvIh.png)

Comment: any help from anybody is appreciated.
thanks

Comment: remove "babel-core": "^6.26.3" from package.json and run npm install. To avoid these configuration issues, react recommends using create-react-app to bootstrap your applicaiton.

Comment: thanks for your fast response.

now error is

**Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not an option for you to use react from cdn?

https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html

How you are a rookie, i recommend to use cdn and "web server for chorme", chorme extention. After get some experience you can jump to node stuff.